# Количество вызовов обработчика события при динамическом добавлении элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('#addUserButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#addUser').append('<div class="addUser__input"><input class="addUser__input-name" type="text" placeholder=" Петр"><input class="addUser__input-spec" type="text" placeholder=" f/F" maxlength="1" pattern="[dbfDBF]"><input class="addUser__input-price" type="number" placeholder=" 2000" min="0"></div>');

    $('.addUser__input').on('click', function() {
        usersIndex = $('.addUser__input').index(this);
        console.log(usersIndex);
    });
});
```

Я понимаю, что повторные вызовы функции идут от двойного события клика (нажимаю однократно), но непонятно почему когда создаешь новые элементы к начальному элементу, вызовы увеличиваются в зависимости от индекса. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Вот здесь видно что идут вызовы в количестве обратном индексу:

[image: Пример]

Отформатированный код:

[image: код]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в навешивании события внутри обработчика.

В строке `$('.addUser__input').on('click', function() {` выбираются все элементы `'.addUser__input'`, а не только добавленные.

Вместо этого нужно было воспользоваться делегированием. Так как все добавляется в `'#addUser'`, то и обработчик можно вешать на него

```
$('#addUserButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#addUser').append('<div class="addUser__input"><input class="addUser__input-name" type="text" placeholder=" Петр"><input class="addUser__input-spec" type="text" placeholder=" f/F" maxlength="1" pattern="[dbfDBF]"><input class="addUser__input-price" type="number" placeholder=" 2000" min="0"></div>');
});
$('#addUser').on('click','.addUser__input', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Вот так и знал, что сначала надо ответ написать, а потом вопрос форматировать)

Comment: @Regent, ну так ничего не мешает добавить ответ с хорошим описанием  ;-)

Comment: Так решение у меня было такое же, описание - выходило плюс-минус таким же. А простыню теории на пару-тройку экранов и смысла-то тут писать нет. Неужто, кстати, на ruSO нет каноничного ответа на подобные вопросы?

Comment: @Regent, их искать тяжело :-) но каноничного, прям хорошего-хорошего - нету

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны навешивать обработчик только на созданный элемент, а не на все:

```js
$('#addUserButton').on('click', function() {
  let div = $('<div class="addUser__input"><input class="addUser__input-name" type="text" placeholder=" Петр"><input class="addUser__input-spec" type="text" placeholder=" f/F" maxlength="1" pattern="[dbfDBF]"><input class="addUser__input-price" type="number" placeholder=" 2000" min="0"></div>');
  div.on('click', function() {
    usersIndex = $('.addUser__input').index(this);
    console.log(usersIndex);
  });

  $('#addUser').append(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addUserButton">Add</button>
<div id="addUser"></div>
```